# Proceso de versionado en git(rama master -usuario)

Tags: git, github, control-de-versiones

Soy algo novato con el versionado directo en github. Entiendo que normalmente cada colaborador del repo debe crear su propia rama y el primer paso debería ser bajar cambios del servidor,segundo modificar y tercero enviarlos al servidor,pero en mi caso quiero trabajar directo sobre la master. Hasta ahora he hecho lo siguiente:

- He creado repositorios (repo inicial en maquinaA)
- he clonado el repo de la rama master(en maquinaB) y está guardado en mi directorio local

Si pretendo hacer cambios sobre esa misma rama, con el mismo usuario que inicié el primer commit(en maquinaA),existe un comando para loguearme a github e indicarle que se trata del mismo usuario?;es decir ahora estoy en maquinaB quiero   hacer push a master.

Comment: Recomiendo leer sobre Gitflow: https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

Comment: @fedorqui consideras apropiado que en el título pase de github a git?

Comment: @BetaM probablemente, pues no veo nada específico de github

Comment: Responder a esta pregunta es casi crear un tutorial sobre Git, y va a estar abierta a opiniones (usar master vs crear siempre ramas y hacer PRs). Si alguien encuentra un buen tutorial en español para empezar con Git y los flujos básicos se podría poner directamente en la [información de la etiqueta git](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info)

Comment: @fedorqui,@BetaM ya he reeplanteado mejor mi pregunta, agradesco su aporte